Are there any plans to launch a Crew Dragon with more than 4 seats?
Spacex's Crew Dragon capsule was designed to hold up to 7 people, but NASA and private flights so far use it with 4 passengers only (from the past and planned flights listed on Wikipedia.)
NASA announced a few days ago that the two Starliner astronauts currently on the ISS will return with the Crew-9 mission, which will launch with two empty seats out of four.
This made me question why they didn't send a dragon with space for 6 while keeping all four initial Crew-9 astronauts. I assume the answer to that is that additional seats would take too long to install or that it would require a brand new capsule altogether.
My actual question is:

Will they ever fly more than 4 astronauts in a Crew Dragon capsule built for more than 4? Strapping people to the cargo pallet does not count.
Have there been considerations on having a spare Capsule with many seats lying around in case they ever need to rescue stranded astronauts like this?


"why they didn't send a dragon with space for 6 while keeping all four initial Crew-9 astronauts." I think the real answer to that is that if they sent up all of the Crew-9 folks they would end up with a lot of people on the ISS for a long time.

To answer the title question, SpaceX has not publicly stated any plans to increase the number of seats on the Crew Dragon capsule. The change in design from seven seats to four seats was due to a safety requirement by NASA regarding seat angle, so it is unlikely that NASA would approve a design for additional seats for flights to the International Space Station. I realize that part of your question relates to contingency situations, which I will also address.
SpaceX could conceivably fly a modified Dragon capsule with additional seats on private missions. However some of the private missions do not dock at ISS and the astronauts spend the entire mission inside the Dragon capsule. Increasing the crew size beyond four astronauts may not be as comfortable for that duration. It would also require SpaceX to determine through their own studies that they believe that the NASA seat angle requirement is overly cautious. As for private missions that dock at ISS, it seems somewhat unlikely that NASA would allow more than four private astronauts to visit the space station at a time, due to station resources. However a limit was not specified in NASA's 2019 announcement of private astronaut missions, which only specified that two short duration (up to 30 days) private missions would be allowed each year. Although the announcement did state:

Private astronaut missions will use a U.S. spacecraft developed under NASA’s Commercial Crew Program.

and by 2019 when the announcement was made it was known that both Dragon and Starliner were each being designed for four astronauts.
Originally Dragon was going to carry up to seven astronauts:

Crew Dragon interior circa 2014 (SpaceX)
According to SpaceX president and chief operating officer Gwynne Shotwell during a meeting with reporters in December, 2019, NASA changed the specification for the angle of the seats because of g-forces that astronauts might experience during splashdown.

With this change and the angle of the seats, we could not get seven anymore. So now we only have four seats. That was kind of a big change for us.


SpaceX Crew-2 astronauts on board their recovery ship, November 2021 (NASA)
Originally Crew Dragon was going to land propulsively. The change to water splashdown changes the dynamics and direction of the g loads. Part of this is due to the tilted angle that the capsule impacts the water at, and it also introduces possible variables in horizonal velocity due to wind, as well as possible wave impact at the moment of splashdown.

Inspiration4 splashdown, September 2021 (Inspiration4)
Contingencies
A separate topic is the possible need for more than four astronauts to return from ISS in a Crew Dragon capsule during some specific contingency situations. Normally during a contingency such as an environmental control problem on ISS, or a medical emergency, astronauts would return to Earth in the vehicle that they arrived in (in the case of Soyuz this is sometimes a different but similar vehicle). However if the vehicle that they are assigned to for deorbit is deemed not safe to use, in an emergency they would need to return in another existing vehicle currently docked at the station.
This potential situation existed for NASA astronaut Frank Rubio in December 2022 when the Soyuz MS-22 capsule that he rode up in developed a coolant leak. Due to possible increased cabin temperature, NASA decided that the capsule was not safe, and so while waiting for the uncrewed MS-23 replacement capsule to arrive, for any contingency departures of the station during that time period Rubio was assigned to the SpaceX Crew 5 capsule. In fact according to a NASA blog post Rubio's Soyuz seat liner was transferred to the Crew Dragon.

On Thursday, Jan. 12, the International Space Station mission management team polled “go” to move NASA astronaut Frank Rubio’s Soyuz seat liner from the Soyuz MS-22 spacecraft to Dragon Endurance to provide lifeboat capabilities in the event Rubio would need to return to Earth because of an emergency evacuation from the space station. The seat liner move is scheduled to begin Tuesday, Jan. 17, with installation and configuration continuing through most of the day Wednesday, Jan. 18.

Rubio's seat liner would have been installed underneath the four Dragon crew seats. How Rubio and his seat liner would have been secured during deorbit and landing was not specified.
NASA astronauts Butch Wilmore and Suni Williams will face a similar situation in early September 2024 when the Boeing Starliner capsule that they rode to the station on will be autonomously undocked from the station for an uncrewed return to Earth, due to technical problems with its RCS thrusters. For about a month until the Crew 9 Dragon arrives they will be assigned to the Dragon Crew 8 capsule in case of a contingency departure from ISS.
According to the NASA media conference held on August 7th, 2024, NASA  modified the previously planned procedure in order to allow a crewmember without a seat liner to ride on the cargo pallet of Dragon underneath the existing seats, using what is referred to as a "foam configuration". This contingency method will no longer be needed after Crew 9 arrives with two crew members, as there will now be two empty seats available for Butch and Suni, which they would use both for contingency departures of the station as well as for their planned return in the Crew 9 capsule in the spring of 2025.
EDIT – more information about the foam configuration was provided in a NASA news conference on September 4th, 2024 a few days prior to the expected departure of Starliner from the International Space Station.  As stated by NASA Commercial Crew Program Manager Steve Stich:

We've configured in the cargo area on Crew 8 what I would call temporary seats. So we've used some of the items on the space station to build a temporary seat for Butch and Suni. As you have seen for launch in Starliner or even Dragon, the crew needs to have their feet in a certain location, their knees bent, and so we have this temporary seat configured for Butch and Suni. It has a number of straps associated with that that goes around them and secures them in place should we ever need to use it. We don't intend to ever use it but it would be some extreme contingency where we had to get away from station quickly where they could use that. We've analyzed that from air flow perspective and we've got good air flow down there, we know that they can get the air they need. We've practiced hand signals for communication should we need that, and we've also analyzed it for the landing and parachute event and the loads on the body are acceptable in these temporary seats that we've configured.

One of your questions is about the possibility of configuring a Crew Dragon with additional seats for similar contingency situations. There have been no statements from NASA or SpaceX about this possibility, so at the moment we can only speculate on the challenges involved. First of all this would have probably been an unlikely solution for the current Starliner situation. In theory Crew 9 could launch with the originally scheduled four astronauts, and also include two contingency seats installed for Butch and Suni to use on return. However as pointed out in a comment to your question, this would expand the Expedition size by two people, something that may not be desirable from a station resource point of view for that length of time.
The bigger reason why this solution seems unlikely is because it would be relegating Butch and Suni to landing in a less safe seating arrangement, since it has already been established that only four seats can be installed at the required angle. While it would likely be decided that this additional risk would be acceptable for a contingency departure when there are no other alternatives, there would be no need to impose this risk for a normally scheduled departure from the station. Thus the decision to fly Crew 9 to the station with two empty seats for Butch and Suni.
In theory one or more contingency seats could be installed on future Crew Dragon capsules, to be used in the event of similar future situations. However it still does not solve the problem, as the contingency seat(s) would not be at the safe angle. It can be argued that even so it must certainly be safer than being strapped to foam on the cargo pallet. While intuitively that would seem to be the case, that is something that would have to be quantified through analysis to determine how much safer such a seat would be. Since the expectation for needing to make this type of contingency return is considered low, if the improvement in safety would be minimal, it may be considered not something that they would consider. Especially since by the time such a seat was designed and tested and installed, there would likely be just a few more years remaining in the ISS program. Nevertheless it's possible that NASA and SpaceX are looking into this possibility, but if so it's not something that they have discussed publicly.
As for whether SpaceX might modify Crew Dragon for higher crew capacity for use at future commercial space stations, that is certainly a possibility, if they feel that it can be done safely by whatever safety standards they or their commercial customers would require.

Thank you for the answer! I did no know about the angle of the seats issue. Does having a wrong seat angle compare to the retro-rocket firing at the end of landing on Soyuz capsules?

Maybe I should open a separate question for that

@Speedphoenix - from what I understand the change in seat angle was primarily because of the tilt angle that the capsule splashes down at. Landing flat would cause what is essentially a bellyflop, landing at an angle cuts in a little more like diving into a pool. Dragon originally was going to land flat on the ground, with no parachute! Soyuz lands pretty much flat, with the retro rockets slowing it down at the last second. So the Soyuz seat angle is designed for a flat landing as well.
